# Calling a stored procedure via Java code, getting errors PLS-00201: identifier must be declared

Tags: java, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I'm take a result set that is being built in prior code and I can see the values from that list are pulling while running in debugger.  When I try to execute my stored procedure call it fails with the following error on the callableStatement.execute();:

PLS-00201: identifier 'INFPL01.LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Here is my code:

```
public List<ProcedureResult> 
callLWN_XML_PURCHASEORDERProcedureAndSendMQMEssage(List<YmpohdroutDbo> list)
{
    DSConnection dsc = new DSConnection();

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    String LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER_Sql = "{call "+PurchaseOrder.dbProperties.getProperty("Schema") +".LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
    /*
     * stored procedure LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER
     * 
     *  in_company IN NUMBER,
        in_PO_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
        in_po_release IN NUMBER,
        in_po_code IN VARCHAR2,
        in_object_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
        RET_CODE OUT NUMBER,
        RET_MSG OUT CLOB)
    */

    List<ProcedureResult> result = new ArrayList<ProcedureResult>();

    try {
        dbConnection = dsc.getConnection();

        YmpohdroutDbo obj;
        ProcedureResult res;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            obj = list.get(i);

            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER_Sql);

            // register input fields of stored procedure
            callableStatement.setInt(1, obj.getCompany());
            callableStatement.setString(2, obj.getPO_Number());
            callableStatement.setInt(3, obj.getPO_Release());
            callableStatement.setString(4, obj.getPO_Code());
            callableStatement.setString(5, (PurchaseOrder.projProperties.getProperty(Constants.SEC_KEY_COMMENT_TYPE))); 

            // register output fields of stored procedure 
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.CLOB);

            // execute LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER store procedure
            callableStatement.execute();

            res = new ProcedureResult();
            res.setCode(callableStatement.getInt(6));
            res.setMessage(callableStatement.getClob(7));

                // send response from stored procedure execution to MQMessages
                PurchaseOrder.writeClobMQMessage(res.getMessage());

                // mark record as processed by updating field INTERFACE_STS to P
                markRecordAsProcessed(obj, dsc);

                // Send procedures result as MQMessage before processing next record
                result.add(res);
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error(e);
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {

        if (callableStatement != null) 
        {
            try
            {
                callableStatement.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            DSConnection.close(dbConnection, null, callableStatement, null);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tried looking at the other posts on this, but it doesn't appear to be the same situation.  I'm guessing its the way I'm building my string, but all the examples I've been seeing are doing it in a similar way.  Thank you!

Comment: Does the stored procedure `LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER` exist in the schema `INFPL01`?  How did you verify that the name is correct?  Does the DB login user under which you're running have the necessary rights to see/execute that procedure?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the response, I have verified the naming convention is correct and it does exist in the schema INFPL01.  I use Rapid SQL and I can pull up the stored procedure and pass my values into and get the expected response.  We use trusted user accounts that have access to this procedure.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database instance? How do you know `dsc.getConnection()` returned the right connection? Did you verify that? Clearly, whatever instance you are connecting to does not believe the procedure exists.  Do you have test and deployed instances?  And BTW, these are all questions you should have asked yourself before posting, and when posting you should have stated all the troubleshooting steps you have done.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jim!  I'm new these as you can probably tell from my low number ha.  I'm investigating the connection right now, thanks for the suggestion.  I was thinking it was an issue with the way I built my string to call the procedure.